# Lattice Point Geometry

Tags: geometry

A student of mine asked me the following question:

Three lattice points (points with integer coordinates) are chosen at random with replacement (meaning you can select the same point more than once) in the interior of the square defined by $-99 \le x \le 100$ and also $-99 \le y \le 100$. The probability that the area of the triangle thus formed (which may be degenerate) is an integer can be expressed in the form $m/n$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $m + n$.

I know the answer. However, I need an explanation with the answer.

Thank you!

Also I have just a few hours before I go back to teach him.

Comment: Can you add the question's answer to your question? It would help the people reading and answering your question.

Comment: This seems like a typical competition question. Does $m+n$ happen to be an integer between $0$ and $999$?

Comment: I don't know, Arthur. The student said that he needed homework help, but he didn't mention the homework type. It can't be AIME, can it? It's just too simple for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not the prettiest way, but at least it's simple:

If you label $\{a_1,b_1\}$, $\{a_2,b_2\}$, $\{a_3,b_3\}$ the three point, the coordinate are independent random integers between $-99$ and $100$. In particular they have a fifty-fifty chance of being even.

The area of the triangle is 
$$ \frac{1}{2} |(a_2 - a_3) b_1 + (a_3 - a_1) b_2 + (a_1 - a_2) b_3| $$

So it's an integer if and only if $(a_2 - a_3) b_1 + (a_3 - a_1) b_2 + (a_1 - a_2) b_3$ is even.

At that point you can just try every possible case ($a_i/b_i$ even or odd, hence $2^6$ cases) and find the result.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll try to explain to the student. Oh my, he's knocking on my door! See you!

Answer (score 0):

Let the three lattice points be $(a_1, b_1)$, $(a_2, b_2)$, and $(a_3, b_3)$. By the shoelace formula (as @Jeannette said), the area of the triangle is
$\frac{|a_1b_2 + a_2b_3 + a_3b_1 - b_1a_2 - b_2a_3 - b_3a_1|}{2}.$
Note that whether or not the triangle has integer area depends only on the parity of the points.

From $-99 \leq x \leq 100$ and $-99 \leq y \leq 100$, we see that each coordinate has an equal probability of being even or odd. Hence, all three points are chosen from the four parity combinations $(even,even)$, $(even,odd)$, $(odd,even)$, and $(odd,odd)$, with replacement. It is true that the triangle have non-integer area iff they are all of different parity combinations (think about it).

We can choose any of the four parity combinations for the first point. The second point has a probability of $\frac{3}{4}$ of having a different parity from the first point. The third point has a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ of having a different parity than the other two points. Hence, the probability that all three points have different parities (and therefore the triangle has non-integer area) is $\frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{8}$.

Therefore, the probability that the triangle has integer area is $1 - \frac{3}{8} = \frac{5}{8}$. The final answer is $5 + 8 = \boxed{13}$.